# innerHTML - using an image

Tags: html, innerhtml

I want to replace File Uploaded with an image.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="file" id="userFile" name = "userFile" accept="image/*"  value="Snap Picture"  style="visibility:hidden;" onchange=" document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = 'File Uploaded';" />
```

I tried the IMG tag instead of File Uploaded but it doesn't work.

Can you please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you forgot to escape the quotes at the img tag:

```
<input type="file" id="userFile" name = "userFile" accept="image/*"  value="Snap Picture"  style="visibility:hidden;" onchange=" document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = '<img src=\'image.png\'>';" />
```

I'd also suggest you to use a syntax highlighting Text Editor

Comment: Doesn't work - shows closing tag on the page. 

Maybe it's because I have this before the input: <a id="a" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('userFile').click(); return false;" />Pick Picture</a>

Comment: Sorry, edited my answer, you have to use these quotes ' instead of the double ones. See it live here http://jsfiddle.net/ZfyZT/

Answer (score 0):

OK, Fixed it.

```
<input type="file" id="userFile" name = "userFile" accept="image/*"  value="Snap Picture"  style="visibility:hidden;" onchange=" document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = '<img src=\'image.png\'>';" />
```